# How can I solve ' sudo: unable to change expired password: Authentication token manipulation error'

Tags: passwords, token, sudo

Whenever I use the sudo command, the following error appears.

```
sudo: Account or password is expired, reset your password and try again
Changing password for root.
(current) UNIX password: 
sudo: unable to change expired password: Authentication token manipulation error
```

However, if i search for a solution to "Authentication token manipulation error", the only answer is to run "sudo mount -o remount,rw /", so it returns to the error in the first line :(

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `exit` to exit the terminal or reboot the system then open the terminal again and use sudo will ask you then to change the password now you can use the old password.